# How to use a socket as source in PyFlink?

Tags: python, apache-flink

I would like to use a socket stream as input for my Flink workflow in Python. This works in scala with the socketTextStream() method, for instance

val stream = senv.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000, '\n')

I cannot find an equivalent in PyFlink, although it is briefly mentioned in the documentation. Any help is much appreeciated.

Answer (score 0):

StreamExecutionEnvironment in pyflink do not supply socketTextStream api right now which is only supported in java StreamExecutionEnvironment

May be we can use the add_source api

```
custom_source = SourceFunction("org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SocketTextStreamFunction")
ds = self.env.add_source(custom_source, type_info=Types.ROW(Types.STRING()))
```